# Maximum likelihood in exponential family: $\partial_{\theta,\theta} \ln L = -\mathrm{Var}(T)$, $T$ sufficient for $\theta$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I'm confused on how the second derivative of the log-likelihood is computed in an exponential family.

There is a result which says that

> If $T=T(X)$ is the natural sufficient statistic for $\theta$, when the likelihood
>   $$
> L = \frac{h(x)}{c(\theta)} e^{\theta T},
> $$
>   is an exponential family, then
>   $$
> \partial_{\theta,\theta} \ln L = - \mathrm{Var}(T).
> $$

So I tried when $X$ is a single observation from a Bernouilli$(\theta)$, but I get that
$$
\left. \partial_{\theta,\theta} \ln L \right|_{\theta=\hat \theta} = -\frac{1}{x(1-x)} \ne 
\left. - \mathrm{Var}(T) \right|_{\theta=\hat \theta} = - x (1-x).   
$$

They are inverse of each other!
What am I missing?

Here are the detail of my calculations.
\begin{align}
L &= \theta^x(1-\theta)^{(1-x)} \\
\ln L &= x \ln \theta + (1-x) \ln (1-\theta) \\
\partial_{\theta} \ln L &= \frac{x}{\theta}-\frac{1-x}{1-\theta} \\
\partial_{\theta,\theta} \ln L &= -\frac{x}{\theta^2}-\frac{1-x}{(1-\theta)^2}
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
\hat \theta &= x \\
\left.\partial_{\theta,\theta} \ln L \right|_{\theta=\hat \theta}
&=-\frac{1}{x(1-x)}
\end{align}
and, for the sufficient statistic,
$$
\mathrm{Var}(T)=\mathrm{Var}(X)=\theta(1-\theta).
$$

Comment: Th explanation is that Bernoulli distributions are an exponential family, but not for the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton Are you shure you do not loose negative power? In the second equation what you have on the right is one over the Fisher information of the test statisics and it is less or equal (in case of exponential family pdf's) to the variance of this statistics. See [Cramér–Rao bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound)

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache I think you mean 
$$\mathrm{Var}(T) \ge (E(-\partial_{\theta,\theta} \ln L))^{-1},$$
the Cramer-Rao lower for the variance of $T$.  
From my calculation, this works, and it explains why they are inverse of each other.   Thanks for your input, combine with Did comment, I better understand what is going on.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton Yep, that's exactly what I mean.